# IOS 5: obtaining sample buffers from a file in a loop

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, media, avfoundation

After many hours of reading of documentation supplied by Apple I am still confused. Say, I can figure out a way to access the sample buffers through AVCaptureDevice family in a periodic manner. But it is not clear how can I do the same with AVAssetReader family. Say, I want to obtain **periodically** audio sample buffers, while their source is an MP3 file. How could that be done?

Comment: To be honest I can figure out some original way. the question is whether exists some generally recommended methodology and relevant API.

Answer (score 1):

To decode any audio file supported by Apple:

```
NSString *songName = @"song.mp3";
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", resourcePath, songName]];

AVURLAsset *song = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:path options:nil];

AVAssetReader *reader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:song error:nil];

NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:48000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
    nil];

AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:[[song tracks] objectAtIndex:0] outputSettings:outputSettings];

[reader addOutput:output];

bool reading = [reader startReading];

CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];

while (sampleBuffer != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:%.1fms]", CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)) * 1000);
    NSLog(@"Buffer contains [SAMPLES:%ld]", CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer));
    NSLog(@"Buffer contains [DURATION:%.1fms] worth of audio", CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer)) * 1000);
    sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
}
```